# Truffle hangs forever with parity with PoA

Tags: truffle, parity, dapp-development, dapps, truffle-migration

I'm trying to create a private chain using `parity` (PoA) and `truffle` but when I do `truffle migrate` it hangs forever with the following output:

```
   > [
   >   {
   >     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   >     "id": 24,
   >     "method": "eth_getFilterChanges",
   >     "params": [
   >       "0x0"
   >     ]
   >   }
   > ]
 <   [
 <     {
 <       "jsonrpc": "2.0",
 <       "result": [],
 <       "id": 24
 <     }
 <   ]
```

### Steps to Reproduce

Create a chain with the following `custom_chain.json`:

```
{
    "name": "DemoPoA",
    "engine": {
        "authorityRound": {
            "params": {
                "stepDuration": "5",
                "validators" : {
                    "list": [
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "params": {
        "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
        "networkID" : "0x2323"
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "authorityRound": {
                "step": "0x0",
                "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        },
        "difficulty": "0x20000",
        "gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } }
    }
}
```

.. config file `note0.toml`:

```
[parity]
chain = "custom_chain.json"
base_path = "./"
[network]
port = 30300
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[ui]
port = 8180
[websockets]
port = 8450
```

.. and command:

`parity --config node0.toml`

Then create two users:

```
curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"parity_newAccountFromPhrase","params":["node0", "node0"],"id":0}' -H "Content-Typ e: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540

curl --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"parity_newAccountFromPhrase","params":["user", "user"],"id":0}' -H "Content-Typ e: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540
```

.. and restart node with the following `custom_chain.json`:

```
{
    "name": "DemoPoA",
    "engine": {
        "authorityRound": {
            "params": {
                "stepDuration": "5",
                "validators" : {
                    "list": [
                        "0x00Bd138aBD70e2F00903268F3Db08f2D25677C9e"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "params": {
        "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
        "networkID" : "0x2323"
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "authorityRound": {
                "step": "0x0",
                "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        },
        "difficulty": "0x20000",
        "gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
    },
    "accounts": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
        "0x004ec07d2329997267Ec62b4166639513386F32E": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" }
    }
}
```

.. `node0.toml`:

```
[parity]
chain = "custom_chain.json"
base_path = "./"
[network]
port = 30300
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
[ui]
port = 8180
[websockets]
port = 8450
[account]
password = ["node.pwds"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x00Bd138aBD70e2F00903268F3Db08f2D25677C9e"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

.. `node.pwds`:

`node0`

.. and command:

`parity --config node0.toml`

Then unlock user account:

```
curl --data '{"method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x004ec07d2329997267Ec62b4166639513386F32E","user",null],"id": 1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8540
```

And try to connect with `truffle compile && truffle migrate` with the following `truffle.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8540,
      network_id: "0x2323",
      from: "0x004ec07d2329997267Ec62b4166639513386F32E"
    }
  }
};
```

### Expected Behavior

`truffle` does the initial migration

### Actual Results

Hangs forever.

### Environment

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Ethereum client: parity1.9.4
- Truffle version (`truffle version`): 4.3.1
- node version (`node --version`): 8.1.3
- npm version (`npm --version`): 4.1.1

P.S. I had similar problem with `geth` but there I attached to IPC socket and called `miner.start()` - it helped. Here there is no miner object as there is no PoW (I'm trying to use and need PoA for my dapp).

Comment: did u found an answer what a problem was?

Comment: @DeV1doR Eventually I switched to using Hyperledger Fabric as I didn't want to mine eth, I just wanted to create a dapp on top of a private network

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/Godtide/1a84c98d1dc7ec434672bed17f3dd09c

For more clarification.

````
/*
 * NB: since truffle-hdwallet-provider 0.0.5 you must wrap HDWallet providers in a
 * function when declaring them. Failure to do so will cause commands to hang. ex:
 * ```
 * mainnet: {
 *     provider: function() {
 *       return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'https://mainnet.infura.io/<infura-key>')
 *     },
 *     network_id: '1',
 *     gas: 4500000,
 *     gasPrice: 10000000000,
 *   },
 */
````

Answer (score 0):

Configure your network in the truffle configuration. Notice that truffle expects the network id as decimal value. An it is a good idea not to store private keys in your project files.

Try something like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();

let PrivateKeyProvider = require("truffle-privatekey-provider");

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*",
            gas: 8000000
        },
        mynetwork: {
            provider: new PrivateKeyProvider(process.env.PK, process.env.PROVIDER),
            network_id: "8995", // 0x2323
            from: process.env.ACCOUNT,
            gas: 8000000
        }
    }
};
```

The .env file should look like (notice that the private key has no leading 0x string.):

```
PROVIDER=http://127.0.0.1:8540
ACCOUNT=0x0####################################
PK=341##########################################################
```

Migrate to your blockchain with:

```
$ truffle migrate --network mynetwork
```